# Remove all HTML <button> elements with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to build a program to run a function every time I press a button, and output the returned value. To do this, I use the following HTML:

```
<h2>Test Results:</h2>
    <strong><span id='runs'>0</span> tests</strong><br>
    <div id='testResults'>
        <button id='test' onClick='this.parentNode.innerHTML = initiatePlanB()'>Begin</button>
    </div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
var tests = document.getElementById('runs');
var inner = document.getElementById('testResults').innerHTML;
//Here's the part I can't figure out
var wo = inner.replace(??????, '');
var out = wo + '<br><strong>Test #' + String(Number(tests.innerText) + 1) + '</strong><br>';
tests.innerText = Number(tests.innerText) + 1;
//More stuff here
return out;
```

Basically, I need either a regex expression, or some other function that can remove any html tag and it's contents.

Comment: How about `<button.*?<\/button>`?

Comment: Don't do it with a regexp. Clone the node, and then manipulate the DOM directly.

Comment: If you are dealing with JavaScript tests you might want to have a look at Jasmine. It is a JavaScript test framework which does a pretty good job.

Comment: I may kindly refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just find all buttons using `getElementsByTagName('button')`

and then remove them all?

```js
var testCount = 0;
var tests = document.getElementById('runs');
var inner = document.getElementById('testResults')

function initiatePlanB() {
  var buttons = inner.getElementsByTagName('button');
  if (buttons) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].remove();
    }
  }

  testCount++;
  inner.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br><strong>Test #' + testCount + '</strong><br>');

  tests.innerText = testCount;
  //More stuff here
}
```

```html
<h2>Test Results:</h2>
<strong><span id='runs'>0</span> tests</strong><br>
<div id='testResults'>
  <button id='test' onClick='initiatePlanB()'>Begin</button>
</div>
```

Though you should probably just hide the buttons, or disable them.